# How to disable and modify password validation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I want the end-user to set the password like a numeric pin of min & max length to 6 characters while registration.
e,g: `234123`
Yes, this can be insecure but the project needs to do it with 6 digit pin.
As `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`  doesn't allow to do it.

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 9, 
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

So how to disable and modify [password validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation) in Django. Without changing the [AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS)  If we have to change the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, then how to achieve it.

Comment: Have a look at the code of the given validators or [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/passwords/#writing-your-own-validator), then implement your own and make it the only entry in `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`.

Comment: Thanks, @KlausD. It's working after adding custom validators. And removing Django Default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a simple validator for the pin:

```
# app_name/password_validation.py

from re import compile as recompile

class PinValidator:
    pin_regex = recompile('\d{6}')

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if not self.pin_regex.fullmatch(password):
            raise ValidationError(
                _('The password must contain exactly six digit'),
                code='pin_6_digits',
            )
```

and then use this as the only validator:

```
# settings.py

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {'NAME': 'app_name.password_validation.PinValidator', }
]
```

That being said, a six-digit pin is usually not a good password: it has only 1'000'000 items. If later the database is stolen, it is also very easy to obtain the PINs by brute forcing this.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**

**How to modify password validation in Django**

Created some validators in validators.py in the `config` dir which is also the Django project name.

```
#validators.py
import re
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

'''
The main purpose of these validators is to accept the password like 6 digit pin only
'''


class LengthValidator:
    def __init__(self, length=6,):
        self.length = length

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if len(password) != self.length:
            raise ValidationError(
                _("This password must contain only %(length)d characters."),
                code='password_should_6_digits_pin',
                params={'length': self.length},
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _(
            "Your password must contain only %(length)d characters."
            % {'length': self.length}
        )


class NumberValidator(object):
    def __init__(self, min_digits=6, max_digits=6):
        self.min_digits = min_digits
        self.max_digits = max_digits

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if not re.findall('\d{0,10}', password):
            raise ValidationError(
                _("The password must contain only digit between, 0-9. like : 012690"),
                code='only numbers are required',
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _(
            "Your password must contain only digits between, 0-9. like: 012690."
        )


class NoUppercaseValidator(object):
    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if re.findall('[A-Z]', password):
            raise ValidationError(
                _("The password must not contain uppercase letter, A-Z."),
                code='password_upper',
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _(
            "The password must not contain an uppercase letter, A-Z.",
        )


class NoLowercaseValidator(object):
    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if re.findall('[a-z]', password):
            raise ValidationError(
                _("The password must not contain lowercase letter, a-z."),
                code='password_no_lower',
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _(
            "Your password must not contain lowercase letters, a-z."
        )


class NoSymbolValidator(object):
    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        if re.findall('[()[\]{}|\\`~!@#$%^&*_\-+=;:\'",<>./?]', password):
            raise ValidationError(
                _("The password must not contain any symbol: " +
                  "()[]{}|\`~!@#$%^&*_-+=;:'\",<>./?"),
                code='password_with_symbol',
            )

    def get_help_text(self):
        return _(
            "Your password must not contain any symbol: " +
            "()[]{}|\`~!@#$%^&*_-+=;:'\",<>./?"
        )
```

Import these into `settings.py` and then change the `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`
to :

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [

    {'NAME': 'config.validators.LengthValidator', },
    {'NAME': 'config.validators.NumberValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_digits': 6,
            'max_digits': 6,
        }},
    {'NAME': 'config.validators.NoUppercaseValidator', },
    {'NAME': 'config.validators.NoLowercaseValidator', },
    {'NAME': 'config.validators.NoSymbolValidator', },
]
```

That's it. Now Password will only be created like 6 digit pin.

> WARNING !!!!!!!!!!! `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` are now compromised and
> prone to brute force attack. The  Project anatomy was
> required to use 6 digit pin instead of a Password with 2FA so it was modified.

**Note: Using this technique you could also create a single, highly-configurable validator covering these rules and/or others to reuse on all your projects as needed. if you want some strong passwords.**
If anyone needs more explanation. just leave a comment. I'll update the answer.